# VS 2010 Code Readability tips / plugins

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Could you advice some nice navigation / code readability plugins & tips on VS2010 to make a dev's life easier ?

For example, [Indent Guide Lines](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/show-vertical-lines-at-each-indent-level-in-visual-studio-2010/) is a must. Can't do without.

One thing I would like to find is a nice tooltip that quickly shows which (sub)class the current method belongs to (handy for large (multi)class files) (Class view is a pain & does not auto-sync to current method)

PS : Resharper has a footprint which makes it a no-go for my subjective POV.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great addon from MS called **Productivity Power Tools** [(website)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/). I find it very useful. It works with VS2010 Professional and above.

Answer (score 1):

Check Vs10x or JustCode
http://www.axtools.com/
http://www.telerik.com/

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for a free solution I could only recommend [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/)
They have a full suite of addins, someone very useful (Tab Well UI, Searchable Add Reference Dialog) , others very annoying (Quick find, etc).
Luckily, you can selectively disable the annoying ones.
However you will not find an answer to your request here.
The only one that do something as you require is called **Ctrl + Click Go To Definition**

In the same place (Visual Studio Gallery) you will find [VSCommand2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf?SRC=Home) lite version. I never tried it, but the command **Locate Source Files** seems to be exactly the answer at your question